# How to hide a full menu except for items with current-menu-ancestor in WP

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I have a Wordpress site where I'm trying to solve a very simple problem. I have a primary menu at the top and a secondary menu at the left side. The top menu contains level 1 items while the left menu has all the items. For the left menu I am using the built-in *"Custom menu"* widget.

To simplify the looks I would like to only show the items on the left which are relevant to the current area, namely items with `current-menu-ancestor`.

1. Is there any way to do it elegantly, by generating only the needed code in HTML? Either by using some custom function in functions.php (I'm using a Twenty Eleven child theme), or by some *"Advanced Custom Menu"* plugin if there is such?
2. I am trying to do it in CSS, and I'm almost there. I selected the items green what I like to keep and red what I would like to hide, but I cannot apply a CSS rule to `display: none` the red items, because then it hides the green items too.

My CSS so far is this:

```
#secondary ul {background: red;}

#secondary li.current-menu-ancestor ul,
#secondary li.current-menu-item ul {background: green;}
```

Here is a sample page where you can see which are the red items I'm trying to hide and which are the green items I'm trying to keep.

http://kozossegikertek.hu/csatlakozz/

I would like to have only the green items visible on the left menu.

Comment: You can't do it with only CSS changes.

Comment: I did it using CSS. I posted it as an answer. My luck were the <a> tags.

Comment: Then I misunderstood what you originally wanted, apologies for misleading you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I did the pure CSS solution. I'm still up for a WP specific solution if someone can do it:

```
#secondary li a {
display: none;
}

#secondary li.current-menu-item ul a,
#secondary li.current-menu-ancestor ul a {
display: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide an element via CSS, use the `display: none;` property.

For something like the menu, you'll want to use Javascript to change the css of the hidden element(s) when a condition is met (hover/click).